# How to make horizontal navigation with localscroll.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollto

I would like to do an horizontal navigation on my portfolio with local scroll.
This is a gallery of differents pictures.

So i have a (div id="project") with links like that:

```
<div id="projects">

    <ul id="content-slider-inside"> 
        <li id="one" class="pictures"><img src="images/paulotlet1.JPG"     alt="paulotlet1" width="620" height="415" /></li> 
        <li id="two" class="pictures"><img src="images/paulotlet1.JPG" alt="paulotlet1" width="620" height="415" /></li> 
        <li id="three" class="pictures"><img src="images/paulotlet1.JPG" alt="paulotlet1" width="620" height="415" /></li> 
        <li id="four" class="pictures"><img src="images/paulotlet1.JPG" alt="paulotlet1" width="620" height="415" /></li> 
        <li id="five" class="pictures"><img src="images/paulotlet1.JPG" alt="paulotlet1" width="620" height="415" /></li> 


</div> <!-- END PROJECTS -->
```

i would like to do an animation when you click on a little arrow or on a key of the keboard the scroll goes to the next (li class='pictures') of the (div id="projects")

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the demos for more info: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/serialScroll/ and http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/localScroll/

Answer (score 0):

should be something like this:

```
$('ul#content-slider-inside').localScroll({
   target:'#projects',
   axis:'x'

});
```

Make sure that your `ul` has the property `display:inline;`

Comment: Thanks you for the answers but i'm a beginner and i don't understand how can i use the key of the keyboard?

Comment: which key are you referring to?